# Marking up a web page

Tags: android, html, browser, web

Sorry if this is a dumb question but is there a way to easily mark up a web page and have it available for subsequent viewing?

What I'd like to do is similar to  days past when one highlighted various items in their text books.

As an example, suppose I am viewing the page:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

I'd like to highlight portions of the section that describes the two ways to add fragments to an activity.

I have tried printing to pdf (and then use the highlight and comments in the pdf viewer) but depending on the browser, computer and OS, the resulting pdf file's quality  can vary  in terms of layout (e.g. text is overwritten ...). I guess I could save the html code and then edit it to provide highlighted text but is there an simpler alternative?
Thanks in advance.
Jim

Comment: What you want is a great idea, but every browser is different, so you will need to install add-ons for every browser. In my case, I love Firefox, so I will give you some add-ons that may help you : https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/highlightall , https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/textmarker/ , https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/select-text-and-request-url/

Comment: Thanks Jose.  I have installed the add-ons and they work as advertised.  BTW, for a brief period I was opening a saved page in MSVS  then modifying  the text in the design window... a bit too cumbersome.  I'm not sure of the protocol here but I'd like to mark your comment as an answer.

Comment: Ok, JimCzek, I turned my comment into an answer, so you can mark it, thanks! (glad I helped you).

Answer (score 1):

According to some reports, the browser that will ship with Microsoft Windows 10 will include a feature for annotating web pages.  See http://www.theverge.com/2015/1/8/7516489/windows-10-new-browser-spartan-features

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a great idea, but every browser is different, so you will need to install add-ons for every browser. In my case, I love Firefox, so I will give you some add-ons that may help you :

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/highlightall/

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/textmarker/

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/select-text-and-request-url/